# Using a timer to refresh the app in the background

Tags: swift, timer, background, apple-push-notifications, refresh

I was thinking about adding a timer to my app so I can use it to refresh data in the background on a regular basis, instead of sending silent notifications through APNs with a server.

Will Apple reject my app if I do this?

Answer (score 2):

After 8 seconds in background the app will pass to the state of suspended and it will simply stop to execute any code. Plus, there is no warranty that the app will not be killed by the system.

It will simply not work.

For the periodic update using APNs with silent notifications, most likely apple will ban you from sending APNs, if you send too many of them.

The way you do periodic updates for your app while in background/suspended/dead is by using `Background fetch` Background mode.

Please note: You don't decide when or how often the background fetch is executed. it's iOS that will decide based on your app usage per user.

[Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) a link to a tutorial for background modes including background fetch.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) the app life cycle and states.

Comment: It will not work. The app will transition to the state inactive after 8 seconds. in inactive state the app will not execute code.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how much APNs silent notifications is too much? I was thinking about refreshing the app once a minute..

Comment: No, I don't . once a minute for each user is for sure too much tough. I would say maybe once a day.

Comment: Updating an app continually every minute is way, way too much and will most definitely get you app rejected.  Why do you need to update so often?